# Is it possible to have forgetful type synonyms in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghc, existential-type, type-synonyms

If I have a type with a phantom parameter that I only sometimes care about, like this one:

```
data Foo p a b = Bar a b
```

Is there any hack way to write a type synonym `Baz` such that `Baz a b` is `Foo p a b` for some `p` that I've forgotten?

You can't do:

```
type Baz a b = Foo p a b
```

and while you can do (with appropriate extensions):

```
type Baz a b = forall p.Foo p a b
```

It doesn't seem like that does what I want, because I can't convert a value of type `Foo P1 a b` to type `Baz a b`, with a message about a "rigid type variable".

Do you need another layer of contructors to achieve this effect, as below? Could you briefly explain why?

```
data Baz' a b = forall p.Baz' (Foo p a b)
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [this kind of behavior](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/32k1eu/new_in_ghc_710_partial_type_signatures/cqbxmra), but it's not currently supported.

Comment: I wanted this as well, and opened [a ticket for it](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/15008).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There isn't currently a way to do this as a type synonym. However, if you have GHC 7.10, you can turn on the `PartialTypeSignatures` extension and write `Foo _ a b` instead. Use `-fno-warn-partial-type-signatures` to ask GHC not to warn you about each of the holes you leave in this way.

Comment: You can do this by inventing fresh type variables in a lot of cases. Good idea that partial type signatures probably covers the other and saves you from having to make up unique names, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This can't really be done reliably with type synonyms.  You need either existential types or rank-n types.

The problem is that Haskell allows type synonyms to be fully intersubstitutable.  I.e., when you define `type Baz a b = Foo p a b`, then in every context where you have `Foo p a b`, you would be allowed to use `Baz a b`, and vice-versa.   So for example, if you had a function of this type:

```
f1 :: Foo Something a b -> Whatever Something b a
```

Then because of substitutability, that'd be the same type as this:

```
f1 :: Baz a b -> Whatever Something b a
```

And as this:

```
f1 :: Foo p a b -> Whatever Something b a
```

...which then you could specialize to this:

```
f1 :: Foo SomethingElse a b -> Whatever Something b a
```

So, what can you do?  One is to define an existential wrapper type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialTypes #-}

data Baz a b = forall p. Baz (Foo p a b)
```

Alternative way of doing the same thing:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Baz a b where
     Baz :: Foo p a b -> Baz a b
```

Second way you could go: rank-n types and continuation-passing style:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

-- To consume one of these, you pass a "callback" function to `runBaz`,
-- which is not allowed to restrict the type variable `p`.
newtype Baz a b = Baz { runBaz :: forall p r. (Foo p a b -> r) -> r }

makeBaz :: Foo p a -> Baz a b
makeBaz foo = Baz ($foo)
```

Third way, which you've attempted and (I'm told) doesn't work very well: type synonyms + impredicative types (which are required to get `forall` synonyms to occur as type arguments in many cases).